# Cannot run jBoss on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, java, vagrant, jboss

I am trying to install jBoss application server on Ubuntu 12.04. I am using Vagrant.

Here is what I am getting:

```
vagrant@precise32:/usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin$ ./standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=25
6m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.d
gc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.mod
ules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.defau
lt.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

Unable to set property fileName on class org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandl
er: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureProperties(Propert
yConfigurator.java:187)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configureHandler(PropertyCo
nfigurator.java:312)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigura
tor.java:128)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigura
tor.java:86)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:246
)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:231
)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:267)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:265)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.j
ava:265)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:248)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:225)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1289)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.<init>(LogManager.java:1287)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:179)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:156)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:275)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standa
lone/log/boot.log (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFile(FileHandler.java:15
2)
        at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFileName(FileHandler.jav
a:183)
        ... 22 more
17:12:02,635 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS018704: Could not create server data direct
ory: /usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerEnvironment.<init>(ServerEnvironment.java:3
88)
        at org.jboss.as.server.Main.determineEnvironment(Main.java:242)
        at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:260)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:291)
vagrant@precise32:/usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin$
```

Comment: You are installing from Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: No I downloaded the file:
wget http://download.jboss.org/jbossas/7.1/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final.zip

Comment: try this link. and follow the steps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012549/how-to-install-postgresql-v9-1-and-jboss-as-v7-1-1-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts#14012550 If it doesn't work write back

Comment: So did you get a fix or did you just giveup